# Error detected on pass 2 at Winmips64

Tags: assembly, mips, mips64

I have some assembly code which is giving me the error:

> Errors detetected on pass 2

It highlights the `halt` command at the end in red. If I press "ok", the program opens but when I try to run it, I think it behaves differently from what I expected (more cycles).

Code:

```
.data
.text
main:
ld $s2, 0($s1)
ld $s1, 40($s6)
dsub $s6, $s1, $s2
dadd $s6, $s2, $s2
or $s3, $s6, $zero
sd $s6, 50($s1)
halt
```

Comment: `halt` is not a MIPS instruction.

Comment: and how can i end the programme?

Comment: It's ASM, you can just let it fall off the bottom and it will automatically end

Comment: oh ok thank you ! :D if u want write it as a post down to check it :)

Comment: _"you can just let it fall off the bottom and it will automatically end"_ That's not a particularly good idea. The program should explicitly terminate or return to its caller. I believe WinMIPS64 supports using system call 10 as `sys_exit` just like SPIM/MARS.